# Algorithm to take samples from binomial data

Tags: binomial-distribution, algorithms, sample, weighted-sampling

I am faced with the following problem : I have binomial data, ie. data of the form trials/successes, with a list of features.

What I need is to sample without replacement from that data, ie. take a fraction $p$ (in my case 50%)of the examples. Since the data is aggregated, this is tricky.

So far my algorithm is the following : Denote by $h_i,c_i$ the number of trials/successes on each line, and $h'_i,c'_i$ the sampled trials/successes. 
I compute the total number of trials $H$ and then randomly generate $pH$ distinct integers between $1$ and $H$. I also compute the cumulative sum $(s_i = \sum_{t\leq i}h_t)_{i<n}$ of successes. 
Then for each sampled integer $k$, I find the first index $i$ such that $k \geq s_i$, and increment $h'_i$. If $k-s_i \leq c_i$ then I increment $c'_i$.

This algorithm works, but the problem is that when generating the random integers, I must store the whole list of integers, which means allocating space proportional to $H$, which in my case is incredibly large, and causes heap to overflow (I use JAVA with a 2Gb heap).

Any ideas to avoid storing that huge vector ? Or another simpler algorithm would be nice (I'm sure this one is largely suboptimal).

Edit : I want to add that the overall complexity of the algorithm should not be more than 
$O(log(n)H)$ where $n$ is the number of lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, the crux of the matter is to generate a random subset of the integers $1, 2, \ldots, H$ of predetermined size $k = pH$ without having to store the entire subset.  This suggests we try to generate it as an ascending sequence $0\lt i_1\lt i_2\lt \cdots\lt i_k\le H$ by producing the $i_j$ in order, thereby reducing RAM requirements to a small constant value.  To that end, note that for any $x \in H$ the chance that $i_1 \gt x$ is the proportion of $k$- subsets of $\{1, 2, \ldots, H\}$ that are actually subsets of $\{x+1, x+2, \ldots, H\}$ and thereby equals

$$\binom{H-x}{k} / \binom{H}{k} = \frac{(H-x)(H-x-1)\cdots(H-x-k+1)}{H(H-1)\cdots(H-k+1)}.$$

The probability mass function for this distribution consequently is

$$p_{H,k}(x)= -\binom{H-x}{k} / \binom{H}{k} + \binom{H-(x-1)}{k} / \binom{H}{k} = \binom{H-x}{k-1} / \binom{H}{k},$$

$\ 1 \le x \le H-k+1.$

Therefore if you can sample $i_1$ efficiently from this distribution, you can proceed recursively to sample $i_2 - i_1$ from the distribution determined by $H-i_1$ and $k-1$ and so on.  Until the very end of this process, the ratios $k(j)/H(j)$ = $(k-j)/(H-(i_1+\cdots+i_j))$ will stay close to $p$.

When $p\gg 0,$ the mass of this distribution is concentrated on small $x$.  (After all, the expected gaps between $i_j$ and $i_{j+1}$ are around $1/p$, so $x$ will only rarely be larger than a small multiple of $1/p$).  For large $H$, this distribution is closely approximated by a geometric distribution with ratio $1-p$ ($ = 1/2$ in this case) and the approximation is excellent for small $x$.  This indicates that a simple rejection-sampling procedure will work well, creating a $O(k)$ algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, quite elegant, not exact but interesting nonetheless.

Comment: @Youloush What is it you think is inexact here? (Note that the use of approximation before rejection sampling doesn't make the result inexact.)

Comment: To amplify on @Glen_b's point: after drawing a value from a geometric distribution, you randomly make a keep-or-discard decision with a suitable probability determined by [the ratio of the geometric mass to the correct probability mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling). Because the multiplier $M$ is close to $1$ and in the vast majority of initial draws the geometric approximation is good, there will be few times any value is discarded. Thus, for little more than the cost of sampling from a geometric distribution, you sample *exactly* from the intended distribution.